# How to save texture bake image file to local drive in python

Tags: python, scripting, uv-image-editor

How do i access and save a image file ?

[image]

Under Image there is a Save As - option

i need to know how to access this and save the image to some location.

```
bpy.ops.image.save_as(save_as_render=False, filepath="\\\\C:\\JCJ\\Desktop\\3d_Project\\fbx\\1\\Textures\\ElementName.png", relative_path=True, show_multiview=False, use_multiview=False)
```

This line of code is what i have been trying to get to work. Doesn't work though. I hope someone has an answer or a tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [Image ID datablock](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bpy.types.Image.html) has a [save_render](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bpy.types.Image.html#bpy.types.Image.save_render) method.

```
bpy.data.images["Image Id Name"].save_render("C:/path/to/file.png")
```